# Subversion: Can't merge external folder

Tags: svn, svn-externals, svn-merge

I have  a folder in my subversion repository that point to an external resource.
Updating the folder works fine, but when I try to merge the folder into another folder, I get the following error:
svn: E160013: '/pharma/!svn/bc/29/branchtest/shared' path not found
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, show external definition and full merge command

Comment: dschmidt@dschmidt-Latitude-E6320:/home/share/Users/dschmidt/Projects/pharma/testexternals$ svn propget svn:externals -R
. - shared https://subversion.advanstar.com/veterinary/branchtest/shared/

dschmidt@dschmidt-Latitude-E6320:/home/share/Users/dschmidt/Projects/pharma/testexternals$ cd trunk
dschmidt@dschmidt-Latitude-E6320:/home/share/Users/dschmidt/Projects/pharma/testexternals/trunk$ svn merge ^/testexternals/shared
svn: E160013: '/pharma/!svn/bc/62/testexternals/shared' path not found